# How to program a vertical database layout of a data set

Tags: java, database, intersection

I want to construct a vertical data base layout( in Java).
like:

```
ABCDE

10110
00101
11101
```

etc.
here `ABC` are attributes and `01` are their values. 
and I want to apply intersection on these columns to extract the resultant value.
would you like to help me?

Comment: please add more efforts. sure we'd like to help...

Comment: What does *apply intersection* mean? Please detail.

Comment: Please provide any code that you have tried and a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector<String> attName = new Vector<String>();
Vector<Vector<String>> rows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

attName.add("A");
attName.add("B");
attName.add("C");
attName.add("D");
attName.add("E");

Vector<String> oneRow = new Vector<String>();
oneRow.add("1");
oneRow.add("0");
oneRow.add("1");
oneRow.add("1");
oneRow.add("0");

rows.add(oneRow);   //first row

oneRow = new Vector<String>();
oneRow.add("0");
oneRow.add("0");
oneRow.add("1");
oneRow.add("0");
oneRow.add("1");

rows.add(oneRow);   //second row
```

and so on....